# Run keyDown function only once

Tags: swift, macos, function, swift2

I am creating an OS X Swift SpriteKit game, but am still quite new to programming. I am trying to run the keyDown function only once while a key is being held down. Currently, if a key is held down, it rapidly repeats the code. I am trying to make it so that I can play a running animation for my game character once (so it will repeat forever until the key is not pressed anymore), because on the keyUp function it will go back to playing the idle animation. Instead of playing the running animation it just freezes on the first texture because the code is being repeated too quickly without leaving time for the full animation to play out. Is it possible to only trigger the action once?

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

if theEvent.keyCode == 124 {
        //Move right
        runningRight = true
        runRightOrLeft(player)
        player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(RunTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1)))

        }
}

override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    //Go back to idle animation
  player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(IdleTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1)))

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`isARepeat` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsevent/1528049-arepeat) of your `NSEvent`. Just make sure your code only runs when this property is false. E.g. by putting this line at the beginning of your function:

```
guard !theEvent.isARepeat else { return }
```